# Nethereum and Metamask via Asp.Net?

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets, nethereum

I'm using `Nethereum` on the server currently,  manually creating `Account` objects using private keys copied/pasted from a MetaMask wallet.  I'm now trying to build access to this functionality through an existing AspNet Core MVC application.

Is it possible to somehow connect a MetaMask wallet to Nethereum using a web front end that is *not* a Blazor component?   I've checked out the Nethereum Blazor sample and it appears to rely on essentially running the Nethereum library in the context of the browser which defeats the performance goals of running on the server in the first place.

How can I securely collect and transfer Metamask wallet credentials to the server's Nethereum instance using some kind of "connect wallet" button?

This is the blazor sample: https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.Metamask.Blazor

It it matters, the idea is for the server to execute Ethereum/BSC trades for the connected wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for that:

https://medium.com/coinmonks/secure-asp-net-core-2-api-with-ethereum-blockchain-88001d5ddb6